An analytical solution to the zero-energy bound state in d-wave superconductor
In the review paper by Sato & Ando (page 11, equation 92), the author claims a solution for the zero mode at the boundary (with a flat dispersion). But when I plug it back to the equation, it is close, but not an eigenstate
The author has
$$H(-i \partial_x, k_y) |{u(x,k_y)}\rangle= 0, \quad \text{with } x>0 \\  H_\mathbf{k} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\hbar^2 \mathbf{k}^2}{2m} - \mu
 &
 \frac{\Delta_0 }{k_F^2} k_x k_y
 \\
 \frac{\Delta_0 }{k_F^2} k_x k_y
 &
 -\frac{\hbar^2 \mathbf{k}^2}{2m} + \mu
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
|{u(x,k_y)}\rangle =
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ -i \text{sgn}(k_y) 
\end{bmatrix}
\sin(\sqrt{k_F^2 - k_y^2} x) e^{-x/\xi}
$$
with $\mu =\varepsilon_F =  \frac{\hbar^2 k_F^2}{2m} $ and $\xi^{-1} = \frac{ \Delta_0 k_y}{2 \varepsilon_F}$.
But then I check
$$
H(-i \partial_x, k_y) |{u(x,k_y)}\rangle
=
\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}
\left[
\left(\frac{\Delta_0 |k_y|}{\varepsilon_F} - 2\xi^{-1} \right)
 \sqrt{k_F^2 - k_y^2}  \cot(\sqrt{k_F^2 - k_y^2} x)
 +
 \frac{\Delta_0 |k_y|}{\varepsilon_F} \xi^{-1} -\xi^{-2} 
\right]  
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ i \text{sgn}(k_y) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ $$
\times
\sin(\sqrt{k_F^2 - k_y^2} x) e^{-x/\xi}.$$
Fixing the final expression to zero gives the "correct" $\xi^{-1}= \frac{\Delta_0 |k_y|}{2\varepsilon_F}$. However, it also requires $\xi^{-1}= \frac{\Delta_0 |k_y|}{\varepsilon_F}$, which only holds when $k_y=0$ and implies $\xi \rightarrow \infty$.
Can anyone give a bit of explanation here?

Please point to a specific equation if you're going to link a 45-page document. Also note that you're linking to a review article by two authors, not one by a single author, so it's not entirely clear if you have the right link.

@Anyon Thank you, I added the page and formula number.
